# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'ｘｘｘｘｘｘ' is denied.'

Tags: vb.net

This INFURIATING!

For some reason ALL attempts to save files in my code NOW get the above message.

I just created a new VB.Net project with TWO lines of code:

```
    xml.Load("C:\Users\acarp\Desktop\test.xml")
    xml.Save("C:\Users\acarp\Desktop\\test.xml")
```

ACCESS DENIED error

I am the Administrator
File is not Read Only
I can open the file and save it without issue using OTHER applications

WTF is going on, as this is happening in ALL of my code, including apps that are already compiled...

This shouldn't be rocket science for a solution, it's TWO lines of code!!!

(I have looked through previous replies to this issue - none of them address the simplicity of the issue - something must have changed on my Dev system, as I have been coding all week without this issue...)

Any help greatly appreciated...

Comment: Are you running your code as Administrator?

Comment: Yes. Same error.

However, I just moved the files to the appdata/local directory and I am able open and save without the error...

Something has CHANGED in the dev environment that is restricting my access...it is baffling

Comment: I just ran the Visual Studio Updater, and  it seems to have resolved the issue...

NO idea how...

Thank you for the response...

Comment: You do realise that that second line has an extra slash in the path, right? I'm not sure whether that would be responsible for this issue but there's no good reason for it regardless.

Comment: Ah, yes, that was a typo on my part...there was just something strange going on with my system as the update seemed to fix everything...thank you for the response..